# Determine function name within that function

Tags: r

How can I get the function's name within that non-anonymous function?  below I assume there's a function or process to do this called `magical_r_function()` and what the expected outputs would be.

```
my_fun <- function(){
      magical_r_function()
}
my_fun()
## [1] "my_fun"


foo_bar <- function(){
      magical_r_function()
}
foo_bar()
## [1] "foo_bar"

ballyhoo <- function(){
    foo_bar()
}
ballyhoo()
## [1] "foo_bar"

tom_foolery <- foo_bar
tom_foolery()
## [1] "tom_foolery"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```r
as.character(match.call()[[1]])
```

Demo:

```r
my_fun <- function(){
  as.character(match.call()[[1]])
}
my_fun()
# [1] "my_fun"
foo_bar <- function(){
  as.character(match.call()[[1]])
}
foo_bar()
# [1] "foo_bar"
ballyhoo <- function(){
  foo_bar()
}
ballyhoo()
# [1] "foo_bar"
tom_foolery <- foo_bar
tom_foolery()
# [1] "tom_foolery"
```

Comment: Tyler, I certainly don't mind (and GG's is good, too), but what was your criteria for which answer to choose?

Comment: Good question.  Both excellent choices.  Both seemed to work the same in my tests. 
 GG's provided a little more detail.  It was tough to decide.

Comment: Upon closer inspection the last condition of assigning a function to a new name, this one more closely aligns with the original ask.

Comment: Please don't change solely on my comment! I'm not wanking and needing reps (though y'all have a bit more than I do). No, I was just curious. I think both `match.call` and `sys.call` are valid base functions with little difference in "effect" and "requirements". So I was curious to insight you might have in preferring one over the other.

Answer (score 12):

Try `sys.call(0)` if a call object output is ok or deparse that if you just want the name as a character string.  Below are a couple of tests of this.  sys.call returns both the name and the arguments and the [[1]] picks out just the name.

```
my_fun <- function() deparse(sys.call(0)[[1]])

g <- function() my_fun()

my_fun()
## [1] "my_fun"

g()
## [1] "my_fun"
```

### Function names

Note that functions don't actually have names.  What we regard as function names are actually just variables that hold the function and are not part of the function itself. A function consists of arguments, body and an environment -- there is no function name among those constituents.

### Anonymous functions

Furthermore one can have anonymous functions and these might return strange results when used with the above.

```
sapply(1:3, function(x) deparse(sys.call(0)[[1]]))
## [1] "FUN" "FUN" "FUN"
```

### Edge cases

There do exist some situations, particularly involving anonymous functions, where `deparse` will return more than one element so if you want to cover such edge cases use the nlines = 1 argument to deparse or use deparse(...)[[1]] or as mentioned by @Konrad Rudolph by using deparse1 in R 4.0.0.

```
Map(function(x) deparse(sys.call(0)[[1]], nlines = 1), 1:2)
## [[1]]
## [1] "function (x) "
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "function (x) "

Map(function(x) deparse(sys.call(0)[[1]]), 1:2)  # without nlines=1
## [[1]]
## [1] "function (x) "             "deparse(sys.call(0)[[1]])"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "function (x) "             "deparse(sys.call(0)[[1]])"
```

### Other

*Recall*. If the reason you want the function name is to recursively call the function then use `Recall()` instead.  From the help file:

```
fib <- function(n)
   if(n<=2) { if(n>=0) 1 else 0 } else Recall(n-1) + Recall(n-2)
fib(4)
## [1] 3
```

*warning and stop* These both issue the name of the function along with whatever argument is passed to them so there is no need to get the current function name.

```
testWarning <- function() warning("X")
testWarning()
## Warning message:
## In testWarning() : X
```

Comment: Your “edge case” is solved elegantly in R 4.0 via the introduction of the `deparse1` function. I’m guessing we should start using that instead of `deparse` by default, once adoption is high enough.

Comment: +1 for `Recall`, which I feel is what OP was really needing.
However, your example of the Fibonacci sequence is not really a good one: it has the problem that you often repeat the calls: for `fib(10)`, `fib(8)` is called 2 times in total (once by `fib(10)` directly, once by `fib(9)`), `fib(7)` is called 3 times, `fib(6)` is called 5 times. See where this is going?

Comment: @Emil, This is right from the Recall help page (as stated in the answer) so it certainly illustrates the point.  If you don't like it on other grounds you can complain to the R developers.

Answer (score 5):

We can also use

```
my_fun <- function(){
  as.character(as.list(sys.calls()[[1]])[[1]])
 }

my_fun()
#[1] "my_fun"
```